# Inefficiency in using 2D CNN on Time-Series Graphs

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I'm using a 2D CNN to analyze Time-Series graphs. For example, my NN is given an image and returns a string (one of 3 classes): [image]

Problem:

- I know this is extremely inefficient. There's a **lot of white pixels** that are in the image. So even if I have a 100 by 100 square image, I'll have 10,000 pixels, most of which are unnecessary. This further handicaps me because I can't even increase the resolution of my images, because that's just too much unnecessary data for the CNN to take in.

Question:

- How can I effectively and efficiently analyze Time-Series graphs if there's so much inherent "useless white pixels" in them?

If anyone can help, that would be great.